# Comparing values in single column to multidimensional array - how to loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops, multidimensional-array

I want to compare values in a Multid array to a values in a single Column.

*Stoploss:*

**45**

54

76

*OHLC:*

37 43 30 40

32 43 41 43

32 **54** 76 87

I want to compare each value in Stoploss to OHLC and find the first value that is larger than Stoploss in OHLC, in this case the first number larger than 45 in OHLC will be 54. And this happens for every subsequent number in Stoploss, adjusting the OHLC array to the row number of the value in Stoploss I want to compare. Which means, when I compare 54 to OHLC, my OHLC range will now become B2:B3 instead of staying at B1:B3.

There will be spaces in the range Stoploss. So far i have this:

```
For i = 63 To 166

Set OHLC = Range("B" & i & ":" & "E" & i)

   For Each cll In OHLC



   If Range("x" & i).Value > 0 Then
   stoploss = Range("x" & i)
   End If

   If cll.Value > stoploss Then

   Range("s" & cll.Row) = cll.Value

   End If

   Next cll

Next i
```

There is no error message in my code, but no values are returned in column "S". I also know this double looping method doesn't work because it returns the first value in range B:E for each row, which is not what I want. Any help guys? Any input will be very appreciated. Thank you

*PS i know topics about this have been covered before, but limited in the VB sphere. Can't seem to find the correct solution. I'm new to VBA.

Comment: Didn't read the full question but it's clear  this `Set OHLC = Range("B" & i & ":" & "E" & i)` should be before `for each` loop.

Comment: shouldnt `cll` actually read `cell` too?

Comment: @BryanDavies hi bryan, I've already formatted cll as a variable. So there's no mistake there.

Comment: @newguy Setting the OHLC range within the loop works as well.

Comment: ok, well if you defined it before, thats ok. But I really agree with newguy about reseting a range of OHLC within the for loop of `for each cll in ohlc` is a really really bad idea. If nothing else, you risk having an infinite loop you cannot escape. I do not mind the 'set OHLC' inside the for loop of i =63 to 16, although that also needs a step as -1 or something. because it will go i=63,64,65 etc and never get to 16.

Comment: @BryanDavies okay, thanks. changed that. so do you know how to go around comparing OHLC to my single column?

Comment: As Bryan mentioned, you need to add `Step -1` on the first line. If you don't, it will assume the default step of 1, and since 63>16 the loop will never be run.

Comment: @VincentG sorry it was a typo, it was supposed to be 166. have edited that accordingly.

Comment: Shouldn't the test and the affectation of stoploss be outside the inner loop? It need to be done only once for each i (and not once for each cll).

Comment: and your OHLC range contains only one row, is that exact?

Comment: @VincentG right, have edited that, thanks. it still doesn't solve the issue though.

Comment: @VincentG no my OHLC range contains a multidimensional array, with 4 columns and 10000 rows. i don't know how to fix the loop because right now it goes through every row, then every cell in that row, which is not what i want. i want it to go through every cell in that MultiD array, for eg from B1:E10000.

Comment: I really don't get what you means by "adjusting the OHLC array to the row number of the value in Stoploss I want to compare". Is the range changing?

Comment: @VincentG yes, i want it to be if its possible. sorry i'll edit my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is now you search every row for values larger than the Stoploss in that row because your range `OHLC` only contains one row. So first you search 37 43 30 40 for a value larger than 45 and so on. This doesn't have any hits (at least in your example).

If you want to search all the rows for every value of Stoploss you need to set your range to all of these rows, then loop over them

```
'Set OHLC = Range("B1:E10000") 'If you want to search the whole range

For i = 63 To 166
    'Set OHLC = Range("B" & i & "E10000") 'if you want to search from row i onwards
    If Range("X" & i).Value > 0 Then
        stoploss = Range("x" & i)
        Set OHLC = Range("B" & i & "E10000") 'based on your comment "first row of OHLC to match the row of the value in Stoploss" (only update OHLC if stoploss is updated)
    End If

    For Each cll In OHLC    'will loop row by row
        If cll.Value > stoploss Then
            Range("s" & cll.Row) = cll.Value
            Exit For    'don't loop through all 40000 cells!
        End If
    Next cll
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked well. However is there any way to make OHLC a variable range instead of setting it as B1:E10000 so that i can make my range changing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You already know how to make a range using a variable as the row?

Comment: If you've set B1:E10000 how is that variable? the rows are variable for range X, but not for OHLC i think. Your code works only when I set B63:E10000

Comment: I need to make my first row of OHLC to match the row of the value in Stoploss whenever I'm comparing the values.

Comment: Ah I went with your comment "multidimensional array, with 4 columns and 10000 rows" ... " i want it to go through every cell in that MultiD array". I edited my post

Comment: @jadeliew123 please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem or describe why it didn't solve the problem ;)